# C++: How to convert WMI File Time to Seconds?

Tags: c++, windows, time, wmi

I've been at this for a little a while and am having trouble converting this file time of the following format: `20201219133636.586301-300` into something more "digestible". I'm trying to convert it into seconds, but am lost on how to do that.

Any idea on how to do this in C++? I'm open to Windows functions.

What does the last part of that time even mean?

Comment: Your date time string has the format of `yyyymmddHHMMSS.mmmmmmsUUU`.  Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/cim-datetime

Comment: -300 -> UTC - five hours. [Some reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/cim-datetime)